# Algorithm to not make randomly-placed objects overlap?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

Let's say I have a div and I insert other divs with randomly-generated location values (top, left).

I'd like an algorithm to not make the elements overlap. I could set the position to relative but the elements would overflow out of the container.

[***Here's an example fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/gcXg7/).

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
{
    var elem = $(document.createElement('div'));
    elem.attr('class', 'child').
    css
    ({
        'top': Math.floor(Math.random()*((height-50)-30+1)+30),
        'left': Math.floor(Math.random()*((width-50)-30+1)+30),
        'width' : 30,
        'height': 30
    });
    $('#wrapper').append(elem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not placing very many objects relative to your total area, you can just detect intersections and resample if you get an intersection. By the way though, if you want a uniform random sample from the ways to assign k non-overlapping objects in the area, then choosing the first object globally uniformly random and then keeping it fixed is not the right approach because the object locations could be biased in order to avoid overlap. You'd be better of placing the objects uniformly spaced from one another in some initial nonoverlapping assignment, and then keep choosing one of your objects and wiggling its location a bit, changing direction when you collide with another object. If you do this enough times you'll have essentially a random sample from what you really want to sample from.